# Peewee query with join doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, peewee

I'm new to peewee and currently trying to migrate from normal Python SQlite3 library.

While my code generate a valid SQL query that return result as expected using a SQlite DB browser, trying to get the value of a field return `AttributeError: x object has no attribute y`.

Model:

```py
class TableShows(BaseModel):
    sonarr_series_id = IntegerField(column_name='sonarrSeriesId', unique=True)
    title = TextField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'table_shows'


class TableHistory(BaseModel):
    sonarr_series_id = ForeignKeyField(TableShows, field='sonarr_series_id', column_name='sonarrSeriesId')

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'table_history'
```

Peewee Query:

```py
data = TableHistory.select(
        TableShows.title,
        TableHistory.sonarr_series_id
    ).join(
        TableShows
    ).order_by(
        TableShows.title.asc()
    )
```

Resulting SQL query:

```sql
SELECT "t1"."title", "t2"."sonarrSeriesId"
FROM "table_history" AS "t2"
INNER JOIN "table_shows" AS "t1" ON ("t2"."sonarrSeriesId" = "t1"."sonarrSeriesId")
ORDER BY "t1"."title" ASC
```

Resulting dicts():

```
{'title': u'Test title', 'sonarr_series_id': 1}
```

Why does running this:

```py
for item in data:
    print item.title
```

Return this:

```py
AttributeError: 'TableHistory' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#selecting-from-multiple-sources

You access the data via item.sonarr_series_id.title

You might consider naming your fields something a bit more pythonic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into that direction! I don't believe how I missed this part of the documentation... I finally made it work by adding `.objects()` to my query: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#ModelSelect.objects

Comment: Regarding the naming of my fields, to be honest, they have been created by pwiz and I didn't change them after. I'll look into it. Thank you by the way for this great piece of software! :-)